# Line wise input in c

Tags: c, validation, input, scanf

how can I enforce following input restriction in c?

First line contains float ,
Second line contains float ,
Third line int,

after pressing enter three times in console, program should be able to read each line and put the contents in respective int,int,float variables.

After three enter key press program should not wait for user input and start validation.

some test cases

```
line1: 34
line2:4
line3:12
result: ok

line1: 
line2:4
line3:12
result: not ok 

line1: Hi
line2:4
line3:12
result:  not ok
```

so far I used the basics

```
    scanf("%f",&p);
    scanf("%f",&r);
    scanf("%d",&t);
```

it works fine for test case 1 and 3, but fails when I leave an empty line.

Comment: Do you have to do this with `scanf`?

Comment: Read the lines with `fgets`. Convert with `sscanf` or the `strto_` family of functions.

Comment: I am not allowed to used conio.h. stdio.h only :(

Comment: `fgets` -> trim -> `sscanf` with `%n`

Comment: None of those functions are in <conio.h>. `fgets` and `sscanf` are in <stdio.h>. `strto_` are in <stdlib.h>

Answer (score 2):

You should **always** check the return value of `scanf`.

The reason is that the return value is what `scanf` uses to communicate conversion errors, among other errors. For example, if your program tells `scanf` to expect a sequence of decimal digits, and `scanf` encounters something that doesn't match that pattern, the return value will indicate this failure.

The value returned will be the number of items that are successfully assigned to. For example,

```
char str[128];
int x, y = scanf("%d %127s", &x, str);
```

If `y` is 1, then it should be assumed that `x` is safe to use. If `y` is 2, then it should be assumed that both `x` and `str` are safe to use.

This answers part of your question. The next part is how you can go about ensuring that the input is in the form of *lines*. `scanf` doesn't strictly deal with *lines*; it deals with other units, such as `%d` being an `int` encoded as a sequence of decimal digits (and a sign); it'll return once the decimal digit sequence ends... There's no guarantee that the decimal digits will occupy *the entirety of the line*.

There are actually two problems here: leading *and* trailing whitespace. All format specifiers, with the exception of `[`, `c`, `C`, and `n`, will cause leading whitespace to be discarded. If you want to handle leading whitespace differently, you'll need to codify how you expect leading whitespace to be handled.

Consider that discarding user input is almost always (if not always) a bad idea. If you don't care what the remainder of the line contains, you could use something like `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` to discard everything trailing up to and including the `'\n'` newline character... The first statement would attempt to read as many non-newline characters as possible, and the second would discard the terminating newline character. However, if you want to ensure that the input occupies the entirety of the line, then you need to test the value returned by `getchar`.

An example using all of these considerations:

```
/* Test for leading whitespace (including newlines) */
int c = getchar();
if (c != '-' && !isdigit(c)) {
    /* Leading whitespace found */
}
ungetc(c);

/* Test for correct data conversion */
int x, y = scanf("%d", &x);
if (y != 1) {
    /* Something non-numeric was entered */
}

/* Test for trailing newline */
c = getchar();
if (c != '\n') {
    /* Trailing newline found */
}
```

Armed with this information, perhaps you can come up with an attempt and update your question with some code if you have any problems...

P.S. I noticed in the code you wrote, you seem to have `%f` and `%d` confused; `%f` is for reading into `float`s, and `%d` is for reading into `int`s, not the other way around...

Comment: Rejecting input for initial or trailing whitespaces is a bad idea. It is common for many applications to ignore them, so users are used to put them freely. Doing differently just give bad user experience.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sure. As I wrote already, "Consider that discarding user input is almost always (if not always) a bad idea." If you take a look at the examples in the question, however, the OP wants blank *lines* of input to fail; custom handling of leading whitespace is required, and that's the bottom line.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I read *line wise input*, I know that `fgets` + `sscanf` must be used instead of direct `scanf`. Of course you can use `getc`/`getchar` as a workaround, but you can get corner cases, where I find`fgets` + `sscanf` cleaner. Example to get a float alone on a line:

```
char line[80], dummy[2];
float val;
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL)... 
if (sscanf(line, "%f%1s", &val, dummy) != 1)...
// Ok val was alone on the line with optional ignored blanks before and/or after
```

You could also add a test for loooong lines :

```
if ((line[0] != 0) && (line[strlen(line)-1 != '\n'))...
```

Comment: How is that cleaner than `float val; int n = scanf("%f", &val); scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar(); if (n != 1) { /* some error handling */ }`? Adding a test for *loooong lines* adds more clutter to your code than you may realise. You need to account for when `fgets` encounters a line longer than `sizeof(line)` characters, for example... You could use `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();`, but then you'd be using `scanf`... and that's just silly, right? Why bother using the most appropriate tool for the job?

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor your code is indeed much shorter... And silently accepts 3 floats on same line which was forbidden by OP. If you do not require line oriented input, `fgets` **is** overkill. But if you need it, it is the more robust way.

Comment: That code won't "silently accepts 3 floats on the same line"... `int n = scanf("%f", &val);` will read a value into `val`, and then `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` will discard the remainder of the line of input, which is something you can't do cleanly and reliably with `fgets`+`sscanf` alone, because when a line is longer than `sizeof(line)` it'll split the line across two reads. You could use the same code I've used to discard the remainder of the line when that happens, but then you might as well just use `scanf` rather than `fgets`+`sscanf`. `getchar` can do it all, at the cost of clutter.

Comment: There's one thing I don't understand, and that is... Despite the problem with `fgets` + `sscanf` that isn't present when using `scanf` + `getchar`, `fgets` is considered "more robust"?

Comment: `fgets + sscanf` ignore leading or trailing blanks (be them spaces, tabs or `\r`) and reject empy lines because you ask exactly one value per line. With `scanf + getchar`, programmer has to explicitely deal with spaces or tabs when you want to ignore them. Can you immediately see trailing spaces or tab, or even additional `\r` at end of line when you read a text file ?

Comment: Are you confusing `\r` with `\n`? There's another problem which you have yet to see regarding `fgets` + `sscanf`, and that is despite my best efforts to explain it to you... What happens if the user enters a line that's longer than 80 characters? What motivated you to use `if ((line[0] != 0) && (line[strlen(line)-1 != '\n'))` (which has a syntax error, btw) instead of `if (line[strcspn(line, "\n")] != '\n')`? Have you explored all of the tools available to you, yet?

Comment: I know what is an additional `\r`. It is what you get under linux when you read a dos text file. And some old files used to have a `\r\r\n` as end of line. I simply try to apply this rule *be strict on output and tolerant on input*. As I'm used to that construct I no longer find it complex, but I must admit that it is almost always useless... except when you have to process files from foreign systems.

Comment: When moving files from dos to unix, use the `dos2unix` utility... That's what it's there fore. When moving files from unix to dos, use the `unix2dos` utility.